# Why is the average of sum of cost function used to update weight values in neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a question about neural network.
I was reading this online book and stuck on the part of description for the way of updating weights. In the book they update weights by calculating the average of the sum of cost value but why do they have to use the average? How did they come up the idea to use the average?
I find that reasonable for some reason but because I feel like the weight values go down for some reason but I'm not 100% sure why they chose the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under some standard assumptions (training data iid etc) mean is an unbiased estimator of expected value of error.

You could also equivalently take a sum of the errors for your training data.  Mean is more useful than that, because if you took the sum on batches of different size, the scale would be different.